# Отключить автосоздание xml тега в webstorm

Tags: xml, autocomplete, webstorm, tag

После нажатия пробела Webstorm создает XML tag.

Автодополнение выключено

Как от этого можно избавиться?

[image: До]
[image: После]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте значения опций **Settings | Editor | Emmet, Expand abbreviation with** и **Settings | Editor | Live Templates, By default expand with** - похоже, у Вас выбран пробел в качестве одного из шорткатов